# Problem with extension of a continous function

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, first-countable

> Let $X$ a first-countable Topological Space, let $Y$ an Hausdorff Topological Space, let $A\subset X$ a subset ot $X$ and let $f:A\rightarrow Y$ a continous function.
> Prove that, if there is an extension
> $$\overline{f} :\overline{A}\rightarrow Y$$
> $\overline{f}$ is solely determined from $f$.

I thought that:
If there is $g$ that is another extension of $f$, and I call $Z=\lbrace x\in \overline{A}\mid \overline{f} (x)=g(x)\rbrace$. Then, $Y$ is an Hausdorff Space so, $Z$ is closed in $X$ and,  $A$ is dense in $\overline{A}$ so $A\subseteq Z\Rightarrow \overline{A}\subseteq Z\Rightarrow \overline{A} = Z$

But I don't think it's right because I didn't use the fact that $X$ is first-countable. I have to use also the fact that $f$ is continous so if  $x_{n}\rightarrow x\Rightarrow f(x_{n})\rightarrow f(x)$.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Your thought works. First countability is irrelevant for this, only the Hausdorffness of $Y$ is needed. Probably the first countability was given so that working with sequences is possible. In my opinion, your argument is superior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument works. You may need to elaborate a bit on

> Then, $Y$ is a Hausdorff space so, $Z$ is closed in $X$

and it may be preferable to write $Z$ is closed in $\overline{A}$ there. Whether you need to elaborate or not depends on what properties of Hausdorff spaces and continuous maps can be assumed as generally known.

First countability of $X$ plays no role in it, it was probably assumed to enable arguments with sequences for those who aren't yet used to topological arguments using open and closed sets, neighbourhoods, preimages etc.

I find your argument much preferable to a sequence (or net/filter for the version not assuming first countability) argument.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I was thinking... the other point of view is based on the fact that in a first-countable space a point x\in\overline{A} iff exists a sequence x_{n} such that x_{n}\rightarrow x. This fact with the fact that in an Hausdorff Space there's single limit give the answer, it is right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. For general $X$, the same argument works if you use nets or filters instead of sequences (if you haven't yet met nets or filters, don't worry). But as a rule of thumb, arguments using sequences etc. tend to be less clear and concise than arguments using neighbourhoods, open/closed sets. (There are of course a lot of exceptions to that rule of thumb.)

Comment: Ok, now it's clear. Thank you!